# Google Drive API file lists

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

**What is the best way to get all files contained in a folder using Google Drive API (OAuth2)?**

For example, with Dropbox, it's just a simple query to (1 request):

`https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/dropbox/{folder}`

For Skydrive, it is:

`https://apis.live.net/v5.0/{folder}`

and then querying the `upload_location` (2 requests).

According to the Google API Documentations, for Google Drive, it's possible to make request to

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{folder}/children`

To get data so that `data.items` containing ID of children. However, with this method, if the folder has `n` files, then it requires to make `n+1` requests (1 for getting lists of items, and n for each item).

I think that making `n+1` requests for such basic task is too many. Is that the way Google Drive API designed, or is there a faster method of querying all files (with enough metadata) inside a folder?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the list endpoint and limit results to files having a given parent.

See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='id'+in+parents
```

This returns much more metaData than the children endpoint

Answer (score -1):

I'm no expert but it looks like the way you've described is the way the API is designed. Just from the https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list it looks like it you are intended to get a List of ChildrenReference's, then from each item in that you get its file ID, then use the files().get(fileID) function to get each file from there.

Comment: IMHO, iterating over the item list to re-run a new API call is a pretty bad design. +1 for the mbonnin query solution above.